# Can you use xml datatype based statements on xml stored as nvarchar datatype in mssql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

My datatable looks like this with the artist columns as NVARCHAR(MAX) but holds text which is basically a xml file.

```
Id | Name | Surname | Title  | Location | Artist                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | xxx  | abc     | def    | London   | XML string in Nvarchar  |
2  | xxx  | abc     | def    | Oslo     | XML string in Nvarchar  |
3  | xxx  | abc     | def    | New York | XML string in Nvarchar  |
```

My XML file looks like this

```
<song category="gaming">
<title>Valentine's Day</title>
<artist-main>Fatfinger</artist-main>
<artist-featured>Slimthumb</artist-featured>
<year>2013</year>
<price>29.99</price>
<album>Gamestain</album>
<albumimg>http://download.gamezone.com/uploads/image/data/875338/halo-4.jpg</albumimg>
<songurl>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J0ABq9TnCw</songurl>
```

Can I use a XML datatype based SQL statement shown below on the artist column?

```
SELECT Id, Name, Surname, Title 
FROM @table 
WHERE Artist.value('(/artist-main)[1]','varchar(max)') = '%FatFinger%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is valid XML you can just cast it like this:

```
WHERE (CAST(Artist AS XML)).value('(/artist-main)[1]','varchar(max)') = 'FatFinger'
```

(I removed the % signs around your search string. If you need them, do you maybe intended to use `LIKE` instead of `=`?)

Comment: @Sebastion Thanks Man. I intended to use like.